# Vanishing Relative Homotopy Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a path-connected topological space and $A$ a subspace of $X$. Fix an integer $k$ greater than zero and suppose every map from a connected $i$ dimensional polyhedron to $X$ is homotopic to a map with image in $A$ for each $i\leq k$. For instance, $X$ can be a CW-complex and $A$ its $k$-skeleton. Does this imply $\pi_{i}(X,A)=0$ or $H_{i}(X,A)=0$ for $0<i\leq k$? For a CW-complex and its $k$ skeleton, this is true, but I need the argument in a more general sense.

Comment: If you know that the homotopy can be taken to be constant on the subspace of points which map into $A$ then yes, just by the definition of relative homotopy groups. This is the case for CW complexes by a relative version of the cellular approximation theorem. As a result, by a relative version of the Hurewicz theorem this gives the homology result you ask for. As xsnl points out, this isn't merely a point set issue

Answer (score 2):

As stated, it's not true at all, even for a skeleton of a CW complex. Pair $(D^n, S^{n-1})$ has the required property for any $k$, since disk is contractible and every map is hkmotopic to a constant one, but, obviously, this pair has homology and relative homotopy groups of a sphere.